# Явные ожидания Selenium

Tags: java, авторизация, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Недавно начал интересоваться автоматизацией в тестировании и в качестве объекта для изучения выбрал рандомный сайт (ссылка будет ниже).

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой, которую вот уже три дня не могу решить собственными силами. На странице http://pdd.by/educ/  есть гиперссылка в тексте **карточки активации Учебной программы**, которая открывает некое изображение.

Нужно дождаться полной загрузки всех компонентов в том числе и кнопки [close] что бы продолжить дальнейшее выполнение тестов.

Из того что пробовал я:

```
public void waitForOpenImg(){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("lightbox-secNav-btnClose")));
    }
```

А так же вот

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#')]"));
```

С различными комбинациями xpath и id.
Но к следующему шагу программа переходит так и не дождавшись загрузки какого-либо из элементов.

Может быть кто-то подскажет как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Обычно достаточно ждать доступности котроллов c которыми юзер должен взаимодействовать. Порой еще полезно дождаться всех ajax-запросов. Суть проблемы не раскрыта, что не так?

Comment: Следующий шаг теста начинается не дождавшись загрузки элементов

Comment: Быть может сайт работает неправильно и появление элемента в DOM не означает готовность? Для кнопок/ссылок лучше ждать кликабельность.

Comment: @free_ze, Вы хоть намекните как это реализовать

Comment: suit ниже показал тот метод из `ExpectedConditions`. Вообще, нужно сначала понять, что означает понятие "готовность" и ожидать выполнение всех необходимых условий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Распространенная стратегия написания теста - это дождаться элемента, с которым будем взаимодействовать в следующем шаге. Причем лучше всего дождаться возможности совершения именно того действия, которого хотим совершить. Например, если хотим посмотреть какой-то атрибут или текст элемента, то достаточно дождаться `presenceOfElementLocated`, а если будем кликать, то лучше `elementToBeClickable`.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#jquery-lightbox a#lightbox-secNav-btnClose")));
```